# running upload in profile

Tags: php, oop, file-upload, upload

I was able to code this one:

```
<?php

      if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
          if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
              echo 'Please choose a file!';
        } else {
               $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

              $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name']; //file   //line 75
              $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.' , $file_name))); //line 76
              $file_temp =  $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']; // line 77


               if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                //upload file

               } else {
                  echo 'incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                   echo implode(' , ' , $allowed);


          }
        }

      }

      if (empty($user->data()->profile) === FALSE) {
      echo '<img src="', $user->data()->profile, '" alt= "', $user->data()->profile, '\'s Profle Image">';

      }
    ?>
```

and then suddenly it has an error with:

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\coding_exam\index.php on line 76

Comment: Please make yourself clear.

Comment: Question unclear. Don't know what you are seeking for. One down vote for that. Keep smiling.

Comment: I'm sorry if you didn't understand the question. I'll revise the question...as you've seen my code above...this is my code for the uploading a image file in profile system.

Comment: when I run the code on my localhost it says "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\coding_exam\index.php on line 76" But the output is already there. Is there any way that could get away the strict standards or is there need to be revise based on my code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($user->data()->profile) === FALSE) {
   echo '<img src="', $user->data()->profile, '" alt= "', $user->data()->profile, '\'s Profle Image">';
```

You can't use like this way $user->data()->profile. This is the problem here.